# How to loop over child objects of master object in batch object

Tags: apex, batch, master-detail, loop

I have a batch process to update Accounts with address info from the Cust_Address__c object. I use a Junc_Account_Address__c object as a junction. How do I loop through the accounts to update the addresses.
Currently I get the error Loop must iterate over collection:Account

```
global class AddressManager implements 
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    // instance member to retain state across transactions
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Account__c, Cust_Address__c, Recordtype' +
            'FROM Junc_Account_Address__c' + 
            'WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY AND End_Date__c >= TODAY'  
        );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Junc_Account_Address__c> scope){
        // process each batch of records
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Junc_Account_Address__c ac : scope) {
            for (Account acc : ac.Account__r) {
                acc.BillingStreet = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingStreet__c;
                acc.BillingPostalCode = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingPostalCode__c;
                acc.BillingCity = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingCity__c;
                acc.BillingState = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingState__c;
                // add account to list to be updated
                accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
                // increment the instance member counter
                recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
            }
        }
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Shazam!');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, 
            JobItemsProcessed,
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        // call some utility
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is there only one record for junction object `Junc_Account_Address__c` or it can be multiple?

Comment: From which object you want to update information?

Comment: As account is parent of `Junc_Account_Address__c`, `ac.Account__r` is not a list but a single record which you will never get in your query as you are not querying any field from an account object. And for loop work on collections only not a single record. see the line `for (Account acc : ac.Account__r) {`

Comment: @rahulgawale it can be multiple since I will be using record types on Cust_Address

Comment: @RohitMourya  From the custom Cust_Address__c object

Comment: @Thomas Don't you think copying data from Cust_Address__c to Account, you might end up with updating same Account multiple times. Since its a master detail relationship, one Account can be linked with many Addresses.

Comment: @RohitMourya only the active adresses wil be copied . The requirement is to make a difference between a change on for example only shipping adres

Comment: @Thomas, you mentioned in your previous post that the relationship is many-to-many. I assume it is like this: 
```Account >- Junc_Account_Address__c -< Cust_Address__c```
So from Junc_Account_Address__c object, if I take the two foreign keys Account__c and Cust_Address__c, it would make a unique ID, right?

Comment: @HengkyIlawan Yes that is correct Hengky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__r` child relationship query if in your Account object actually has a lookup field to Junc_Account_Address__c. The inner for loop below is not needed.

```
    for (Junc_Account_Address__c ac : scope) {
        for (Account acc : ac.Account__r) {
        }
    }
```

Also, since you are referencing some fields from the `Cust_Address__c`, you need to include them in your SOQL string.
Otherwise you'll get the exception

> "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field"

```
    SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Account__c, 
        Cust_Address__r.BillingStreet__c, 
        Cust_Address__r.BillingPostalCode__c, 
        Cust_Address__r.BillingCity__c, 
        Cust_Address__r.BillingState__c, 
        Recordtype
    FROM Junc_Account_Address__c
    WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY AND End_Date__c >= TODAY
```

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Junc_Account_Address__c> scope){
        // process each batch of records
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Junc_Account_Address__c ac : scope) {
            Account acc = new Account (
                Id = ac.Account__c,
                BillingStreet = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingStreet__c,
                BillingPostalCode = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingPostalCode__c,
                BillingCity = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingCity__c,
                BillingState = ac.Cust_Address__r.BillingState__c
            );
            // add account to list to be updated
            accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
            // increment the instance member counter
            recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
        }
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
```